# Getting [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] tough the value is not nil

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on `UIPageViewController` and I make strong for the global instance in properties below code:

```
UIViewController* aController = someviewController;//(I am getting the aController value)
NSArray* viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:aController, nil]; 
//(I am getting the viewControllers value as well).

[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers 
    direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil]; 
//(I am getting crash here saying [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil').
```

All the instances are holding the values don't know where `viewControllers` is becoming nil.

please let me know

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105471e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010626ddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001053388c5 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 901
3                         0x0000000103df0b5e -[MZDashBoardViewController viewDidLoad] + 1470
4   UIKit                               0x00000001071fbf98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
5   UIKit                               0x00000001071fc2e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
6   UIKit                               0x00000001077d57df -[UIPageViewController _setViewControllers:withScrollInDirection:animated:completion:] + 585
7   UIKit                               0x00000001077d59fb -[UIPageViewController setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:] + 166
8                         0x0000000103decba5 -[MZMainDashViewController viewDidLoad] + 2997
9   UIKit                               0x00000001071fbf98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
10  UIKit                               0x0000000107240651 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 54
11  UIKit                               0x0000000107240f26 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 462
12  UIKit                               0x0000000107241098 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 126
13  UIKit                               0x00000001072422f1 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 890
14  UIKit                               0x00000001072433af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
15  UIKit                               0x00000001073e9ff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
16  UIKit                               0x000000010711c4a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106d8359a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106d77e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106d77cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106d6c475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106d99c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106d9a37c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010539d367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010539d2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105392f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105392828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010988fad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
28  UIKit                               0x0000000107065610 UIApplicationMain + 171
29                        0x0000000103dd2d3f main + 111
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001086e092d start + 1
31  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: OK, so now lets see the code in `[MZDashBoardViewController viewDidLoad]` that is calling `[NSMutableArray insertObject:]`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Just noticed the same, checking it,

Comment: You could have easily detected by setting "All Exception" break-point in XCode and  get the exact code causing the crash. That's the first and basic debugging procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you are trying to insert an object into an immutable array, not a mutable array. Somewhere inside viewDidLoad. Remember just because a variable has type NSMutableArray* doesn't mean it is.